# Do I need external IP for Tor Node?

Tags: ip, tor

after reading articles about tor and how it works-Tor Node too. i want to create my own Tor Node and transfer to my Node my data from the browsing.
I'm using VMware Workstation with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
this is my `torrc` file, copy, paste from tor site:

```
Nickname test
ORPort 443
ExitRelay 0
SocksPort 0
ControlSocket 0
ContactInfo human@gmail.com
```

after running in the terminal the `tor` commend I'm getting messages that its running well and its 
`bootstrapped 100%`

`[notice] Now checking whether ORPort xx.xxx.xxx.x:443 is reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)`

here the error messages starts:

```
[notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts and 100 buildtimes.

[warn] Your server (xx.xxx.xxx.x:443) has not managed to confirm that its ORPort is reachable. Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.
```

i dont know how to handle this error message after a long search what to do.

Comment: You need an external IP for Internet, so also Tor, but that's probably not your problem.
Did you open the correct ports in your router?

Comment: Do you want to be a middle node?

Comment: @davidbaumann i want to be a exit node,do you have any Suggestions?

Comment: Do you understand what being an exit node means? Are you ready to fight allegations for criminal behaviour?

Comment: Read this: https://blog.torproject.org/tips-running-exit-node - if you are asking basic questions on configuration you are NOT ready to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do:

Set your VMWare network adapter as bridged. Bridge it to the interface, that goes to your router.

Use your router to forward port 443 to the ip of the VMWare.

Now it should work.

Comment: how i can set the VMware network adapter as bridged?

Comment: Did this help you? Do you want to set it as solution?`